# How to get the required output with awk and add the output into another file?

Tags: linux, awk

I have `test.gtf` file that looks like below:

test.gtf

```
chr2      Cufflinks       exon    5072    5353    .       -       .       transcript_id "transc_00000019"; gene_id "XLOC_000017"; gene_name "XLOC_000017"; exon_number "1"; inf "unknown"; Other "XLOC_000017";
chr2      Cufflinks       transcript      5072    5353    .       -       .       transcript_id "transc_00000019"; gene_id "XLOC_000017"; gene_name "XLOC_000017"; oId "TCONS_00000019"; class_code "u"; tss_id "TSS19"; inf "unknown"; original_gene_id "XLOC_000017";
chr2      Cufflinks       exon    20450   20769   .       +       .       transcript_id "transc_00000001"; gene_id "XLOC_000001"; gene_name "XLOC_000001"; exon_number "1"; inf "unknown"; original_gene_id "XLOC_000001";
chr2      Cufflinks       transcript      20450   20769   .       +       .       transcript_id "transc_00000001"; gene_id "XLOC_000001"; gene_name "XLOC_000001"; oId "TCONS_00000001"; class_code "u"; tss_id "TSS1"; inf "unknown"; original_gene_id "XLOC_000001";
chr2      Cufflinks       exon    24985   25273   .       +       .       transcript_id "transc_00000002"; gene_id "XLOC_000002"; gene_name "XLOC_000002"; exon_number "1"; inf "unknown"; original_gene_id "XLOC_000002";
chr2      Cufflinks       transcript      24985   25273   .       +       .       transcript_id "transc_00000002"; gene_id "XLOC_000002"; gene_name "XLOC_000002"; oId "TCONS_00000002"; class_code "u"; tss_id "TSS2"; inf "unknown"; original_gene_id "XLOC_000002";
chr2      Cufflinks       exon    43499   43705   .       +       .       transcript_id "transc_00000003"; gene_id "XLOC_000003"; gene_name "XLOC_000003"; exon_number "1"; inf "unknown"; original_gene_id "XLOC_000003";
chr2      Cufflinks       transcript      43499   43705   .       +       .       transcript_id "transc_00000003"; gene_id "XLOC_000003"; gene_name "XLOC_000003"; oId "TCONS_00000003"; class_code "u"; tss_id "TSS3"; inf "unknown"; original_gene_id "XLOC_000003";
```

I'm trying to use the following command on the `transcript` in the 3rd column and trying to get a number using 5th and 4th columns like below:

```
awk -F"\t" '$3=="transcript" {ID=substr($9, length($9)-16, 15); L[ID]+=$5-$4+1}
           END{for(i in L){print i"\t"L[i]}}' test.gtf
```

But the above command doesn't give an output. The output should be looked like the below:

```
transcript_id   num
transc_00000019 282 
transc_00000001 320
transc_00000002 289
transc_00000003 207
```

And I have another file `test2.tsv` like below:

```
gene_id           transcript_id      column3       column4     column5  column6
XLOC_000017      transc_00000019         -             -          -         - 
XLOC_000001      transc_00000001         -             -          -         - 
XLOC_000002      transc_00000002         -             -          -         - 
XLOC_000003      transc_00000003         -             -          -         -
```

The output I got should be added as another column in the `test2.tsv` file and it should look like below:

test2.tsv

```
gene_id           transcript_id      column3       column4     column5  column6     num
XLOC_000017      transc_00000019         -             -          -         -        282
XLOC_000001      transc_00000001         -             -          -         -        320
XLOC_000002      transc_00000002         -             -          -         -        289
XLOC_000003      transc_00000003         -             -          -         -        207
```

Comment: Approximately how many lines are in each of the real files?  What is suitable for a short test file may not be adequate for a multi-million line live data file.

Comment: Are you sure those are tabs and ONLY tabs between each of your fields and the 3rd field doesn't have a blank at the start or end of it? Try running `awk '{gsub(/\r/,"<CR>"); print gsub(/\t/,"<TAB>"), $0} NR==4{exit}' test.gtf` on your file to make sure you only see tabs between fields, have the number of fields you expect, cnd check for DOS line endings and then [edit] your question to show the output of that command.

Comment: I used the command you gave...and it showed first 4 lines as output of that command and also I see there is `1` before `chr2` in all the lines. strange.

Comment: The command I gave is printing the `1` - it's the count of tabs on each line. All of that means the spaces between fields in your file are not tabs which is why setting `FS` to ` tab is not finding a 3rd field and so `$3=="transcript"` is never true.

Comment: ah yes not tabs.

Comment: Regarding `And I have another file...` - that's the start of a completely different question, only ask 1 question at a time.

Comment: Note that if you don't have tabs, this is NOT a valid GFF file and won't be supported by tools expecting GFF input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `awk`, if the delimiter is a space or more, then you can try;

```
$ awk -F' +|"' 'NR==FNR {a[$11]=$5-$4+1;next} FNR==1{$(NF+1)="num"}{print $0,a[$2]}' test.gtf test2.tsv | column -t
```

However, if it is indeed tabs, then you can try;

```
awk -F'\t|"' 'NR==FNR {a[$11]=$5-$4+1;next} FNR==1{$(NF+1)="num"}{print $0,a[$2]}' test.gtf test2.tsv | column -t
```

**Output**

```
gene_id      transcript_id    column3  column4  column5  column6  num
XLOC_000017  transc_00000019  -        -        -        -        282
XLOC_000001  transc_00000001  -        -        -        -        320
XLOC_000002  transc_00000002  -        -        -        -        289
XLOC_000003  transc_00000003  -        -        -        -        207
```

Comment: what is `$11` here? and when I used command on the files it didn't give any values in the column `num`

Comment: if you look at the command I used in the question...it is column 9, where different fields are separated by `;`

Comment: you mean `"` after `'  +|'` can be removed?

Comment: what if the `gtf` is no tabs and `tsv` file is tabs...in that case how to use the command? Do I need to make any changes?

Comment: @beginner You would need to change to the delimiter in use by the file.

Comment: @beginner GTF, like GFF requires tabs. If you have removed the tabs from your GTF/GFF file, perhaps by opening it in some GUI text editor or excel or something like that, then this is no longer a GTF/GFF file. This is really, really important, don't expect these files to work with other applications if they don't have tab-separated fields.

Comment: Sure terdon. thanq. but when I use the above command which is for tab files...it is not working...the first command which is on space delimiter files it worked.

Comment: I understand, @beginner, that's why I am telling you that you have probably broken your GTF file and it is no longer a valid GTF file since valid GTF files require tab-separated fields. So if you try to feed this file to a program expecting GTF or GFF3 format, the program won't like it. By the way, you might want to check out our sister site: [bioinformatics.se].

Answer (score 2):

The spaces between fields in your input are not tabs so don't tell awk they're tabs with `-F"\t"`, just remove that statement and change `ID=substr($9, length($9)-16, 15)` to `ID=substr($0, length($0)-16, 15)` (or use $NF instead of $0 if you prefer):

```
$ awk '$3=="transcript" {ID=substr($0, length($0)-16, 15); L[ID]+=$5-$4+1}
           END{for(i in L){print i"\t"L[i]}}' test.gtf
id "XLOC_000017 282
id "XLOC_000001 320
id "XLOC_000002 289
id "XLOC_000003 207
```

Looks like the numbers you use in your `substr()` call are off and you're missing prepending `transc_`, I expect you can fix that.

The above will work no matter what those spaces in your input are.

By the way, don't use all upper case variable names so they can't clash with builtin variable names, and then never use the letter `l` as a variable name as it looks far too much like the number `1`. Also, use OFS to specify what to separate output fields with:

```
$ awk -v OFS='\t' '$3=="transcript" {id=substr($0, length($0)-16, 15); num[id]+=$5-$4+1}
           END{for(id in num){print id, num[id]}}' test.gtf
id "XLOC_000017 282
id "XLOC_000001 320
id "XLOC_000002 289
id "XLOC_000003 207
```

Comment: why is it giving `id` and why `"` before `XLOC`? and can you give names for the columns?

Comment: Because that's the substring you asked `substr()` to print. Your lines end with `original_gene_id "XLOC_000017";` and you said `ID=substr($0, length($0)-16, 15)` so count 16 chars back from the end of the line and you get `id...`. Yes, I could give names for the columns but I'm sure so could you and that's yet another question. Please just ask 1 question at a time in this forum as the forum exists to help future users with their similar questions and they won't be able to find questions like theirs if those questions are buried in other questions.